# unhide all NSWindows in an app, Objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos, powerpc

Trying to work out how I might unhide all windows in an app simultaneously. I'm doing this for a Power PC app in XCode 2.5 so I would prefer older methods of doing this if there are any. OSX version will be 10.4.11

Comment: What do you mean? Windows aren't hidden. Apps are hidden. Windows may be ordered off-screen (but then they usually aren't known to the user) or minimized or perhaps other things like window-shaded. Also, do you want to do this to your own app's windows or some other app's windows?

Comment: the app is a game, its game window is set to be invisible on start up and when a button in the menu is pressed the IBAction tells all windows in the app to show, then hides the menu window. I say all windows because I'm not entirely sure how to specify which window I want hidden when the view controller class I am using does not know that there are other windows.